# Error while calling DynamoDB low-level API's from C code

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-dynamodb, libcurl

i tried to calling DynamoDB low-level API's from C code. This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>


int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;

    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Host: dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com;");    
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept-Encoding: identity;");
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Content-Length: 53;");    
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "User-Agent: CustomApp42;");
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.0;");
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<Credential>, SignedHeaders=<Headers>, Signature=<signature>;");   
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "X-Amz-Date: 4.4.2016 ;");
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "X-Amz-Target: DynamoDB_20120810.GetItem;");

    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"TableName\":\"Pets\",\"Key\":{\"AnimalType\":{\"S\": \"Dog\"},\"Name\": {\"S\": \"Fido\"}}}");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    /* free the custom headers */ 
    curl_slist_free_all(chunk);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But it produce error while running like

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

I faced mainly two issues.

1. i have aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key. How to create Authorization (SignedHeaders & Signature) using these two credentials?
2. How to modify "X-Amz-Target" for dynamo query method?

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this?

Comment: its difficult for me. because i moved with api gateway. if you give a solution for this, i can improve my dynamo query speed. it also offer better performance to my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to use the [AWS SDK for C++](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp)? It will do all this heavy lifting and more for you. Actually, even if you are making a C program, you can expose an [extern C library](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/thesolution.html) structure to the AWS SDK calls that you need. So, either way, I recommend coding against the AWS SDK for C++, and create an extern C library wrapper in case you need to compile your main program as a C program.